# TIME datatype in SQL Server 2008 will not accept time from Access form

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, types, time

I am using an Access form on the front end, bound to a SQL Server 2008 table. I have an `Arrival Time` column of datatype `Time`.

But I get an ODBC error every time I try to save a record. Error states:

> *Invalid character value for cast specification.*

Time displays as `10:00:00 AM`. I have tried with and without a time format in the properties of the field, and with/without an input mask of various types. Does anyone know how to avoid this error?

Comment: Are you using a linked table? Are you using adp or mdb/accdb? I ask, because I wonder about testing entering the time directly into a linked table, which works for me, admittedly with Express, not 2008.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20212179/4050261 << This Answer is a must read.

Answer (score 1):

When I linked a 'Time' Field from SQL Server 2012 Express to an access front end (2010 accdb) using the old '`SQL Server`' ODBC driver, it converted it to a Text field, and would not allow an updates.  You might consider using a `datetime` field, or trying a newer ODBC driver.  I believe the 'Time' field was first introduced in SQL 2008, so I'm guessing older ODBC drivers don't know how to handle it.