# Display SQL time field on Access form as Access medium time hh:mm am/pm

Tags: sql, time, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010 linked to SQL Server 2008 R2.  My problem - how do I display time on an Access form as `hh:mm am/pm` instead of SQL Server's time(7) format of `hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`?

To complicate things, I do have a look-up table with all the times in half hour time frames? Ex. in SQL, the lookup field says 07:30:00.0000000 - I want to choose a time from the dropdown in my Access form that says 7:30 am and then display it on the Access form as 7:30 am.  If I choose it, I want it to store in SQL Server as `07:30:00:0000000` (because I have no other choice).

I can't find anything on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide a sample of the code you use to pull in the date now?  We can better help you if we know what you are already trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Access doesn't have a `Time` data type, so when it links to a SQL Server `time` column it maps that column as `Text`. That's why any `Date/Time` Format specifier you try to apply to the linked table value has no effect: as far as Access is concerned it's a string.

So if we have a SQL Server table [Appointments]:

[image: sqlTable.png]

and we create a Linked Table in Access we get

[image: accessTable.png]

If we create an Access form for that linked table and use plain old bound controls we get this

[image: form1.png]

The text box for [apptStart] does work, but it doesn't look so great. The workaround is to leave that text box on the form, but hide it (set its `.Visible` property to `No`) and then add another unbound text box to the form. (In this case I called it [txtStartTime].) Set the `.Format` of the new text box to `Medium Time` and adjust any other formatting as required (e.g., I set `Text Align` to `Left`).

In the `On Current` form event, calculate the Access `Date/time` value corresponding to the start time in SQL Server table and stuff that value into the [txtStartTime] text box. Now we get something that looks a little better:

[image: form2.png]

Now what if the user wants to edit that value? In the `After Update` event for the [txtStartTime] text box we create the corresponding SQL Server `time` string and stuff that value into the (invisible, bound) [apptStart] text box. When the record is saved the new time value is updated in the SQL Server table.

The code behind the form is as follows:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const accessDate0 = "1899-12-30 " ' <- note trailing space
Dim startTimeAsDateTime As Date

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.txtStartTime.Value = CDate(accessDate0 & Left(Me.apptStart, 8))
End Sub

Private Sub txtStartTime_AfterUpdate()
    Me.apptStart.Value = Format(startTimeAsDateTime, "hh:nn:ss")
End Sub

Private Sub txtStartTime_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo txtStartTime_BeforeUpdate_Error
    startTimeAsDateTime = CDate(accessDate0 & Me.txtStartTime.Value)
    Exit Sub

txtStartTime_BeforeUpdate_Error:
        MsgBox "Start Time appears to be invalid."
        Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  It works.  Now I'm trying it with the date.

Comment: Amazing in detail explanation. Thanks so much for this Code with screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a dev environment setup, but can you change your SQL query to:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(5), getdate(), 108)
```

to give HH:MM and truncate the rest so it displays correctly.

Then, you can cast as date on the way back.

Comment: I don't have any code.  I have Access tables linked to my SQL database.  On my Access form, I have the look-up going to one table in SQL, and the data going into another table.  In both SQL tables, the time field's data type is Time(7).  I am new to SQL, and knowledgeable in Access and vb.  Even though I understand the code, I'm not seeing where to put the Select statement.  In the Access form, if I go to the field properties, where do I go from there?  Or should I be doing something totally different?  Thanks for your help in advance!