# MS Access bound to TIME filed sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, datetime, ms-access

I have made an Attendance form which records attendance `InTime` I am using MS Access 2016 and linked table is connected to Azure SQL server.

> Access doesn't have a `Time` data type, so when it links to a SQL Server time column it maps that column as `Text`. That's why any `Date/Time` Format specifier you try to apply to the linked table value has no effect: as far as Access is concerned it's a `string`.

Based on Answer >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20212179/4050261

I have added 2 txt fields `txtTimeIn` (unbound) and `TimeIn` (bound). But I am still getting the error

```
Const accessDate0 = "1899-12-30 " ' <- note trailing space
Dim startTimeAsDateTime As Date

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.txtTimeIn.Value = CDate(accessDate0 & Left(Me.TimeIn, 8))
End Sub

Private Sub txtTimeIn_AfterUpdate()
    Me.TimeIn.Value = Format(startTimeAsDateTime, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub

Private Sub txtTimeIn_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo txtTimeIn_BeforeUpdate_Error
    startTimeAsDateTime = CDate(accessDate0 & Me.txtTimeIn.Value)
    Exit Sub

txtTimeIn_BeforeUpdate_Error:
        MsgBox "Start Time appears to be invalid."
        Cancel = True
End Sub
```

[image: Error Message]

SQL Server Table Setup
[image: SQL Server Table]

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use the default SQL driver, then ALL datetime2 columns from SQL server will map as text columns to Access. You might want to consider using the native 11 drivers - such columns will then map correct as datetime in Access. So what you see on the Access client in terms of column type will depend on the SQL driver you use to link to SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date part is not needed:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me!txtTimeIn.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me!txtTimeIn.Value = TimeValue(Me!TimeIn.Value)
End Sub

Private Sub txtTimeIn_AfterUpdate()
    Me!TimeIn.Value = Format(Me!TimeIn.Value, "hh\:mm\:ss")
End Sub

Private Sub txtTimeIn_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    On Error GoTo txtTimeIn_BeforeUpdate_Error
    Debug.Print Format(Me!txtTimeIn.Value, "hh\:mm\:ss")
    Me!TimeIn.Value = Format(Me!txtTimeIn.Value, "hh\:mm\:ss")
    Exit Sub

txtTimeIn_BeforeUpdate_Error:
    MsgBox "Start Time appears to be invalid."
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

However, the simple solution if possible, is to change the time fields to data type *DateTime*.

Update:2017-04-09 (by Adarsh) - There was a small error, in referencing.

> Me!TimeIn.Value = Format(Me!TimeIn.Value, "hh:mm:ss")
>
> Me!TimeIn.Value = Format(Me!txtTimeIn.Value, "hh:mm:ss")

Comment: Since the development is in it's very initial days. I have an option to change the database structure. Please elaborate on `the simple solution if possible, is to change the time fields to data type DateTime.`

Comment: Implemented your solution, it works. There was a small error in referencing control, Have edited your answer. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.